# Correct way(s) to call/trigger an anonymous function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this function, which is like a different version of and utilizes `Array.push` with some different logic inside it:

```
var array_values = [];

function pump_array(needle, haystack, callback) {
    var pushed = false;

    if(haystack.indexOf(needle) === -1) {
        haystack.push(needle);
        pushed = true;
    }

    if(typeof callback == 'function') {
        callback(haystack, pushed);
    }
}
```

And now if I we use it in this manner:

```
var pump_array_callback = function(new_data_in_array_values, pushed) {
    if(pushed) {
        console.log('added "first" into "array_values[]"');
    } else {
        console.log('"first" already in "array_values[]"');
    }

    console.log(new_data_in_array_values);
};

pump_array('first', array_values, pump_array_callback);
pump_array('first', array_values, pump_array_callback);
```

The first function call of `pump_array` will output:

> `added "first" into "array_values[]"`

And second will do the opposite:

> `"first" already in "array_values[]"`

So basically, my question is:

Is this the right way to call/execute an anonymous function in a function, or elsewhere:

```
if(typeof callback == 'function') {
    callback(haystack, pushed);
}
```

And are there any other methods of doing the same, in a more pragmatic way?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I'll update the question!

Comment: The code behaves like you expect it to, doesn't it? You add a value to the array, call a callback – `pushed` is not undefined (truthy), the first case gets evaluated. The second time the value is already inside the array, the parameter `pushed` is undefined, the else-block gets executed.

Comment: You only need some test for `callback` if you want it to be an optional parameter. You only need to invoke it in an alternative way if `callback` expects a specific `this`. Otherwise what you have is fine

Comment: My opinion: I see nothing wrong or sub-optimal with the call itself. And to make sure that there is really an existing function available behind the _callback_ parameter makes sense, of course.

Comment: @aesthaddicts Will `pushed` ever be `undefined` or it will toggle between `true` and `false` in the `pump_array` function? I belive I handled that...

Comment: @hherger Do you think just to check if `callback` parameter is an optional one?

Comment: @PaulS. I understand everything in your comment, except the part _"except a specific `this`"_. Are you talking about a new/different scope inside the `callback` referred with the parent function `pump_array` which may cause some scoping issues?

Comment: @Duvdevan For example, if `this` in `pump_array` should be carried over into `callback` you would invoke as `callback.call(this, haystack, pushed);`. It doesn't seem applicable to what you've written here but is applicable to callbacks in general. Also on the subject of optional parameters, I'd probably just test `if (callback) ...` so that I get a useful error if something wrong is passed rather than a silent fail

Comment: That's what I was interested in the first place. `callback.call(this, haystack, needle)` - so it will actually execute the function inside `pump_array` and `this` inside a callback will be referred to `this` from `pump_array`?

Comment: BTW: "*Is this the right way to call/execute an anonymous function...*" -- is this callback really an *anonymous* function?

Comment: @Dudevan Yes. It's important - at least for me. Stability and robustness is a #1 priority in big and complex projects. It does not cost much, avoids unnecessary efforts, and this mind set of a developer is agood one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your invocation of the callback is fine.

> And are there any other methods of doing the same, in a more pragmatic way?

You should not use a callback at all for this use case. Just use a return value when you can (and you hardly ever *need* a callback).

```
function pump_array(needle, haystack) {
    if (haystack.indexOf(needle) === -1) {
        haystack.push(needle);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

var array_values = [];
function pump_array_result(pushed) {
    if (pushed) {
        console.log('added "first" into "array_values[]"');
    } else {
        console.log('"first" already in "array_values[]"');
    }
    console.log(array_values);
};

pump_array_result(pump_array('first', array_values));
pump_array_result(pump_array('first', array_values));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This use case is for test purposes and to demonstrate my actual problem - invoking the anonymous function. Your answer was very helpful!